# Right way to write Unit-Tests in module?

Tags: python, unit-testing, module

I want to write tests for my main file,`calc.py`,  with unittest in module file, `MyTests.py`.

Here is my main python file, `calc.py`:

```
import myTests

def first(x):
    return x**2

def second(x):
    return x**3

def main():
    one = first(5)
    two = second(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    try:
        myTests.unittest.main()
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```

And here is my `MyTests.py` file:

```
import unittest
import calc

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testInput = 10

    def test_first(self):
        output = calc.first(self.testInput)
        correct = 100
        assert(output == correct)

    def test_second(self):
        output = calc.second(self.testInput)
        correct = 1000
        assert(output == correct)
```

When i run my `calc.py`, i get the following output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why does unittest prints me that "Ran **0** test"?
And what is the right way to write unittest in module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unittests.main()` looks for `TestCase` instances *in the current module*. Your module has no such testcases; it only has a `myTests` global.

Best practice is to run the tests *themselves*. Add the `__main__` section there to the `myTests.py` file:

```
import unittest
import calc

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testInput = 10

    def test_first(self):
        output = calc.first(self.testInput)
        correct = 100
        assert(output == correct)

    def test_second(self):
        output = calc.second(self.testInput)
        correct = 1000
        assert(output == correct)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and run `python myTests.py` instead.

Alternatively, pass in the imported `myTests` module into `unittest.main()`. You may want to move the `import myTests` line *down* into `__main__`, because you have a circular import too. That is fine in your case, `myTests` doesn't use any globals from `calc` outside of the test cases, but it is better to be explicit about this.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    try:
        import myTests
        myTests.unittest.main(myTests)
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```